# X Courses Equals Certification

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a report that will identify that the user took the necessary courses to complete a certification. If user has completed 6 courses, then I want to return that the user is certified. There is a user table and a course table, all courses are in the course table with the user name.

Example
Sally Smith took:

- 100 Donning and Doffing PPE
- 100 Fall Prevention
- 100 Fire Safety
- 100 Standard Precautions in Home Care
- 100 Transmission Based Precautions
- 100 Understanding Coronavirus

These courses would classify her as Certified and I want to show this to the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL to return your data, you could return certification status in a subquery so your query might look something like this:

```
SELECT U.UserId, U.UserName, C.CourseName, X.Certified
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Enrolments E ON E.UserId = E.UserId
INNER JOIN Courses C ON C.CourseId = E.CourseId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT UserId, 'Certified' AS Certified, COUNT(*) AS CoursesCompleted 
   FROM Enrolments
   WHERE CompletionDate IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY UserId
   HAVING Count(*) >= 6) X ON X.UserId = U.UserId
```

This will put "Certified" in the subquery's `Certified` field if the user has completed 6 or more courses, otherwise it will be null.